# Error when installing Google Plugin for Eclipse into /opt on Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, installation, file-permissions

I'm following the steps to install the GPE 4.2(Juno) located here https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.2

I receive the following error when trying to install the GPE.

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse
>   4.2 3.1.0.v201208080121-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group
>   3.1.0.v201208080121-rel-r42)   Missing requirement for filter properties ~= $0: Eclipse Platform
>   4.2.1.v20120814-120134-9JF7BHVGFyMveli1uX6aTH0q-eAap6PAgOP5mO (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group
>   4.2.1.v20120814-120134-9JF7BHVGFyMveli1uX6aTH0q-eAap6PAgOP5mO) **requires 'org.eclipse.core.net.linux.x86 [1.1.200.v20120522-1148]'** but
>   it could not be found   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2 3.1.0.v201208080121-rel-r42 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group
>   3.1.0.v201208080121-rel-r42)
>       To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.8.0

I have eclipse installed for java EE (Juno) on a linux 64bit system (Linux Mint 13)

This only occurs when I try to use the instance of eclipse that I have installed under /opt. I installed another instance of eclipse under my home directory and did not experience this problem. I assume there is a path/permission issue that is causing the problem when trying to use the instance installed under /opt.

What should i do to resolve this problem? I'm trying to conform to the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard. I used the instructions posted here to install eclipse http://colinrrobinson.com/technology/install-eclipse-ubuntu/

Comment: I launched eclipse as root and was able to install the google plugin for eclipse. I was hoping that I could install the plugins to ~/.eclipse, but I see from reading here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Eclipse that may not be a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install your plugins to Eclipse with the proper permissions to access /opt. There are two options:

1. Start Eclipse with sudo whenever you want to install/update plugins.
2. Give your user/group write permissions to /opt/

I personally use #2 and don't have any problems with it.

NOTE: This isn't related to google-plugin-for-eclipse, it is just a generic permissions issue with Linux and your Eclipse install dir.